# Что означает "склеить страницы" веб сайта?

Tags: seo, веб-программирование

К примеру: Необходимо склеить страницы example.com и example.com/en
Могли бы вы привести примеры удачно склееных страниц в интернете. 
Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Данный прием зачастую используется для страниц с дублирующимся контентом.
Почитайте про `rel="canonical"`. Вот [линк](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139394?hl=ru)

Пример:

```
http://site.com/categoryName
http://site.com/categoryName?sort.name=desc
```

Эти две ссылки содержат одну и ту же категорию, но во втором случае сортировка по имени. В результате контент дублируется. Для этого указываем на этих страницах:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://site.com/categoryName">
```